# How to Transfer Data from my PC to S3 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

Can anyone suggest any document for transferring data from my Personal Computer to S3 on AWS. I have about 50GB of data to be transferred and later use spark to analyze the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many free ways to upload files to S3, including:

- use the AWS console, go into S3, navigate to the S3 bucket, then use
  Actions | Upload
- use [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)
- use the [awscli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)
- use [Cloudberry Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To upload from your local machine to S3, you can use tools like [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en).  Some times large uploads may get interrupted ... Tools like Cyberduck can resume an aborted update.

If you already have data onto an Amazon EC2 machine instance, then [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) works pretty well.